# 9900k Cooler Limited To 155mm

Tags: assistive-technology

i'm after a cooling solution to a 9900k, I haven't bought the parts yet, but my case is the one i'm using currently. I'm after an air cooler, however the case has a limit of 155mm of clearance. I've seen many recommendations of the Noctua NH-D15, and the be quiet Dark Rock 4, however both are too large for the case.

The Mobo and ram i'm pairing with it is a ASUS ROG Strix Z390-E Gaming, and Corsair Vengeance 32gb, so 4x8GB kits.

The case for reference is an Aerocool Shard ATX Mid Tower. I'm located in Australia. Thanks all for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Scythe coolers such as

Scythe 'Katana 4' CPU Cooler SCKTN-4000 (143mm) https://www.ebay.com.au/p/Scythe-Katana-4-CPU-Cooler-SCKTN-4000/1437103860?iid=173824696171&rt=nc

Scythe SCKTN-5000 Katana 5 (135mm) https://www.ebay.com.au/c/9026543133?iid=273973469669
http://tech-legend.com/reviews/scythe-katana-5/

Scythe Ninja 4 (155mm) https://www.ebay.com.au/p/Scythe-Ninja-4-High-Performance-CPU-Cooler/22012057588?iid=361579772995&rt=nc

Reliable and quiet coolers, I always recommend and install it myself to friends and customers. There have never been problems with overheating. No one complained about the increased noise.